# Save json object as Jupyter ipynb file

Tags: python, json, jupyter

I have read a Jupyter notebook file (ipynb) into Jupyter as a json object for cleaning up purposes:

```
import json
with open('C:/Python/Scripts/MyNotebook.ipynb') as json_file:  
    jsonin= json.load(json_file)
```

I then remove some blocks of code that don't have the specified string `#keepthis`:

```
jsonout=jsonin
if '#keepthis' not in str(jsonout['cells'][1]['source']):
    jsonout['cells'][1] = np.nan
```

This works fine. How do I now convert jsonout back into an .ipynb file?  I have tried this:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to jsonout 'C:/Python/Scripts/MyNotebookClean.ipynb'
```

But I get this error despite manually creating the `MyNotebookClean.ipynb` file in the same location as the original `MyNotebook.ipynb` file: `[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern "'C:/Python/Scripts/MyNotebookClean.ipynb'" matched no files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to writing the json object back to the ipynb file.  It is simply:

```
with open('C:/Python/Scripts/MyNotebookClean.ipynb', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonout, outfile)
```

Also, I should have used `del jsonout['cells'][1]` instead of `jsonout['cells'][1] = np.nan`